# Extracting a string from the first square brackets, starting from right to left

Tags: r, regex

I am trying to extract the string only from the first square brackets starting from right to left

I have tried multiple approaches using `str_match` and `regexpr` but I couldn't make it.

```
c<-"Sens [91] [DRCol105]_Issuer[Risk\\Issuer]"

str_match(c,"\\[.*?\\]$")

OR

start.char<-regexpr("\\[*$",c)[1]+2
stop.char<-regexpr("\\]*$",c)[1]-1
substr(c,start.char,stop.char)
```

I want to extract everything that is inside the last square brackets. In this example, I would like to extract and save in a variable only "Risk\Issuer".

Comment: Try `str_match(c,"([^\\[]+)\\]$")[,2]` - i.e. select a string of characters that are not `[`, followed by a `]$`.  Note that `str_match` should be used with a capture group `(...)` - unlike `str_extract`

Comment: Hello. Please try and avoid naming objects (or functions) with predefined names. In your case, `c` is for concatenate

Answer (score 3):

Here is another solution using regex

```
# s <- "Sens [91] [DRCol105]_Issuer[Risk\\Issuer]"

gsub('.*\\[(.*)\\]', '\\1', s, perl = TRUE)
# [1] "Risk\\Issuer"
```

The regular expression `.*\\[(.*)\\])` extracts the string inside the *last* square brackets.

Or

```
# s <- c("Sens [91] [DRCol105]_Issuer[Risk\\Issuer]", "123 [91]@[test] something follows")

gsub('.*\\[(.*)\\][^\\[]*', '\\1', s, perl = TRUE)
# [1] "Risk\\Issuer" "test"
```

which has the advantage of working if the string does not end with brackets.

Answer (score 2):

I have changed the string name to `s`, since `c` is a base R function name.

```
s <- "Sens [91] [DRCol105]_Issuer[Risk\\Issuer]"

sub("^.*(\\[.*?\\]$)", "\\1", s)
#[1] "[Risk\\Issuer]"
```

Or, if you want to remove the brackets:

```
sub("^.*\\[(.*?)\\]$", "\\1", s)
#[1] "Risk\\Issuer"
```

Answer (score 2):

Here are few options:

```
tail(stringr::str_match_all(s, "\\[(.*?)\\]")[[1]][, 2], 1)
#[1] "Risk\\Issuer"
```

Using the same regex

```
stringi::stri_extract_last_regex(s, "\\[(.*?)\\]")
#[1] "[Risk\\Issuer]"
```

Or to remove brackets

```
gsub("\\[|\\]", "", stringi::stri_extract_last_regex(s, "\\[(.*?)\\]"))
#[1] "Risk\\Issuer"
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `strsplit` approach,

```
tail(strsplit(x, '[', fixed = TRUE)[[1]], 1)
[1] "Risk\\Issuer]"

#or If you don't want the last bracket,

sub(']', '', tail(strsplit(x, '[', fixed = TRUE)[[1]], 1))
[1] "Risk\\Issuer"
```